# How to let a register contain exactly one ^M without an extra newline?

Tags: macro, register

I'm trying to programmatically record a macro (using `:let @m=` rather than `qm`). In vim, I executed:

```
:let @m = ':retab^M'
```

where `^M` is typed as ctrl+V, Enter. I expect the buffer to contain exactly what is written above, but it also contains a newline at the end, and when the macro is executed, my cursor moves down by one line. If I populate `@m` with the `q` record function, this problem does not occur.

How can I programmatically set a register to contain a `^M` but not an extra newline? Note that `:let @m=":retab\<cr>"` gives the same result.

To elaborate: I expect the `@m` to contain ':retab^M' or ':retab\n' but it actually contains: ':retab\n\n' with an extra newline. Or to say it another way, `:let @m = ':retab^M'` and `qm:retab ENTER q` should give the same result (the identical macro in register `m`), but they differ by a newline character. (The result is the same on Windows and Linux.)

Comment: Please explain with more detailed example what you try to do what you expect and what you get. I mean, given the text, I try to record a macro that should do 'this and that' instead when I execute it I get 'that and this'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to replace c-m to c-j?

like

```
let @m = ':retab^@'
```

Not 100% sure why it happens but...

When you do (with `<C-v><C-m>`)

```
let @m = ':retab^M'
```

The `m` register gets additional 'newline' and looks like:

```
:retab^M^@
```

But if instead of ^M you will insert ^@, no additional 'newline' is inserted and you end up with:

```
:retab^@
```

**PS**

to see contents of the register use:

```
echomsg @m
```

`echo @m` will not show those special symbols.

Comment: This works! Can you tell me what is happening? I can't find `<c-j>` in the docs. (Note: in full, that is `<c-v><c-j>`.)

Comment: I am not 100% sure :)

Comment: BTW, `:h i_ctrl-j` shows no difference with `ctrl-m`.

Comment: Best way to view registers is `:reg [letter]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following, if you don't want to `<C-V>...`:

```
let @m=":retab\n"
```

Note: You need double-quotes. Doesn't work with single quotes.